# Improving a text search function

Tags: c++, performance, full-text-search

I currently have a text search routine that looks something like this:

```
    unsigned match = 0;
    for(unsigned position=0;position<haystack_length;position++) {
        if (haystack[position]==needle[match]) {
            match++;
            if (match==needle_length) {
                // report match at position
                match = 0; // keep on finding matches
            }
        }
        else {
            position -= match;
            match = 0;
        }
    }
```

My intuition says that I'm doing something wrong here.... in particular, it seems that after having a partial match, trying to reset 'position' back to where it was before any matching occurred makes this an O(nm) algorithm as a worst case, n being the length of the haystack and m being the length of the needle.  Also, it strikes me as logically wrong, somehow, to be changing that variable behind the for loop's back, as it were.  Even though I am certain that there are better ways to do this, I can't think of any.

My specific use case, in case any optimizations can be performed for it, is that I will need to search for several different needles in many different haystacks, and the set of needles that I will be searching for in each haystack will be identical.

Any suggestions on how I can improve this both for performance and perhaps making it so that it doesn't feel like a kludge would be most welcome.

Comment: There are other algorithms like [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).

Comment: Does that mean you want to search for all needles (known in advance) in all haystacks (not known in advance)? In which case yours is more like `O(n*m*c)`

Comment: Niklaus Wirth once discussed the Boyer-Moore algorithm in a Scientific American article. If I recall correctly. Worth reading if you can get it.

Comment: http://www.nature.com/scientificamerican/journal/v251/n3/pdf/scientificamerican0984-60.pdf

Comment: Boost has a Boyer-Moore searcher, and the library fundamentals TS adds a `std::experimental::boyer_moore_searcher`, which should be part of gcc v5 (it's in the libstdc++ trunk).

Comment: SIMD may speed up comparisons.  You would need to worry about alignments though (`memcmp` and `strcmp` may use).

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're searching for several "needles" in each "haystack", the comments suggesting Boyer-Moore *probably* aren't the best.

When you're searching for several different targets, you *typically* prefer to use the Aho-Corasick algorithm instead. This is *basically* a trie, but "flattened" into a table format, with some extra "links" added to optimize continued searching when one match fails. Using it, you can search for *all* your needles in a particular haystack simultaneously. At least theoretically, if you're searching for N strings, this could speed up your search by a factor of approximately N (usually somewhat less than that, since the steps in Aho-Corasick are a little more complex than in many other algorithms, but if N is large, the margin can still be quite substantial).

The next obvious step after that would probably be to parallelize the searching across the haystacks. Build a table for the Aho-Corasick search for the needles you care about, copy that to each thread and the threads then search the haystacks.

There are a number of alternatives to Aho-Corasick for multi-string matching, such as the Commentz-Walter algorithm and one called DAWG-MATCH. The latter produces quite impressive results in [its paper](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/articles/ipl3.pdf), but I haven't implemented or tested it personally, so I'm a little hesitant to recommend it too strongly.